# How to collect fractions in SymPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

In SymPy 1.3 I have some linear combinations like

```
N1*(-sqrt(15)/36 + 5/36) - 5*N2/18 + N3*(sqrt(15)/36 + 5/36)
```

How do I force the fractions to be `(5-sqrt(15))/36`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply [`together`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.rationaltools.together), which can be called either as a function `together(expr)` or a method `expr.together()`. If it's applied to the entire expression, the result may be too much collecting:

```
N1, N2, N3 = symbols('N1 N2 N3')
expr = N1*(-sqrt(15)/36 + S(5)/36) - 5*N2/18 + N3*(sqrt(15)/36 + S(5)/36)
print(together(expr))
```

prints `(N1*(-sqrt(15) + 5) - 10*N2 + N3*(sqrt(15) + 5))/36`.

Here is a version that selectively applies `together` to the coefficient of each symbol.

```
for sym in expr.free_symbols:
    expr = expr.xreplace({expr.coeff(sym): together(expr.coeff(sym))})
print(expr)
```

prints `N1*(-sqrt(15) + 5)/36 - 5*N2/18 + N3*(sqrt(15) + 5)/36`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want.

Use sympy's Rational operator to force it to retain 5/36 in fractional form.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> N1 = 2
>>> N2 = 5
>>> N3 = 7
>>> (N1*(-sqrt(15)/36 + Rational(5, 36)) - 5*N2/18 + N3*(sqrt(15)/36 + Rational(5,36)))
-0.138888888888889 + 5*sqrt(15)/36
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'1.3'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is completely the opposite. I want to combine two fractions with the same denominator to one.